# How to make extension read/write from/to file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way at all to make Chrome extension use one or more text files as a database?

I Looked around a bit ant the only similar thing i found was this - http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Btw. I'm using jQuery (to grab information from web and store it in a file on a personal computer)

Comment: Depending on what kind of Data you're trying to save (and I hope it's not user data) you can just use [Web Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage)

Comment: Why this question has java tag? There is a bbbbbbig difference between Java and JavaScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Chrome Extension you can use the `chome.storage` API.

**DISCLAIMER**: As I said in my comment and the chrome extension documentation warns:

> Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.

From the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage):

You need to enable storage permissions in the manifest:

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
      "storage"
    ],
    ...
}
```

and then you can utilise:

```
function saveChanges() {
        // Get a value saved in a form.
        var theValue = textarea.value;
        // Check that there's some code there.
        if (!theValue) {
          message('Error: No value specified');
          return;
        }
        // Save it using the Chrome extension storage API.
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
          // Notify that we saved.
          message('Settings saved');
        });
      }
```

Comment: It is nothing confidential, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.storage` is only available in chrome extensions (which is fine for this question).

But, there are other alternatives (You have to check browser compatibility for each one):

Web Storage, Indexed DB, Web SQL

See this link for more information about pros and cons of them:
http://csimms.botonomy.com/2011/05/html5-storage-wars-localstorage-vs-indexeddb-vs-web-sql.html